# Why do certain commenters take a rude tone with new users?

Tags: support, comments, users, new-users

I saw this question: [Video Player code (JavaScript, HTML5 etc)](https://superuser.com/questions/1610586/video-player-code-javascript-html5-etc), and I thought it might be good to give the person a way to solve the problem, even though it isn't on topic for this website. I've commented:

> “You could use MediaElement.js”

But, my comment was almost immediately removed. Maybe it wasn't good enough because I didn't mention all the possibilities, but then [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) commented the following:

> “We are not a code writing or product recommendation service.”

And blocked my ability to respond. I wanted to respond:

> “@Mokubai why acting like that? all I wanted was to help. and it's the comment section, not an answer. I can't comment? what's wrong with you? also, the person who asked is new. I think it might be fair to guide him for the next time and also tell him the possible solutions for his question on the way. It won't kill you to be kind.”

But rather than discuss it in the comments, I thought it would be better to bring it to the Meta site instead.

What's the big deal to be kind and help the user in the comments, while also attaching the rules and guides how to ask a question? If it's the user's first time here, it's really not the way to attract people to come here. The other commenter user (Mokubai) should be banned in my opinion. I don't feel wanted here and I believe many others feel that way too.

Do you want this website to be for a specific-users only or it should be for anyone and give a chance to all?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm sorry, but as a moderator and longtime community member of the Software Recommendations SE, I can authoritatively state that the reason why we are friendlier is *not* because we are "discussion-based".  It's because we work hard at being friendly. :)

Comment: The main reason to go to from here to Software Recommendations SE is not they are friendly and we're not. The main reason is the asker asked for software recommendations and other users were willing to recommend software. This is explicitly off-topic on SU and the very gist of SR. So if you want to ask for or give software recommendations, go to Software Recommendations SE not because they are nice but because that's the Right Place.

Comment: “This user (Mokubai) should be banned in my opinion.” - You want a community elected moderator to be banned for deleting an unnecessary commentary?  “And blocked my possibility to respond.” - **A moderator closed a question that was asking for software recommendation, why should a moderator be banned for moderating the community?**.

Comment: Comments are for helping the asker, not berating moderators.

Answer (score 12):

It may not be "fair" to lock comments, but the question is entirely off topic for this site and the comments were not doing anything to change that.

If the comments had been "you can edit your question to be on topic" or "try this other site where your question may be on topic" then fine, but they were not. The comments were purely "try this player" and "is there some code where I can do *this* with it?"

Comments should be used for clarification and improvement of the post upon which they appear, they should not be used to circumvent a question closure.

Answering an off-topic question, even in comments, validates the impression that the asker was "right" to ask in the first place. New users don't know about comments or care about whether they got the answer in a comment or a real answer and by "answering" in a comment you are cementing in their minds that we *do* allow these questions when we don't.

Show them the right place and way to ask this kind of question, but do not make the mistake of encouraging them to ask the wrong questions to begin with.

Please read [What are comments?](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment)

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Isn't all the Stack Exchange websites Q&A websites?

Answer (score 5):

### I believe the issue here is not whether or not the comments were appropriate or not, but rather the speed at which the actions were taken.

I really think the timing is the issue here. But first, this…

> “This user (Mokubai) should be banned in my opinion.”

I might have sympathy towards your point of view, but if you truly believe that someone should be banned because their actions rubbed you the wrong way, I cannot trust your point of view.

Perhaps Mokubai acted *too* quickly; which is really what I think is the case here. But stating someone should be banned like this is really too much of a retaliatory swing.

My opinion about this whole issue? Everything [that Mokubai states](https://meta.superuser.com/a/14354/167207) is 100% correct for all of the reasons stated. But… I do strongly believe that *some* Moderators are too quick to act in cases like this. The speed of the response is what I feel has ruffled feathers.

So can I kindly recommend that moderators just wait a bit for the closed question to settle *before* deleting comments? Maybe only act quickly if the comments are truly getting unruly. But otherwise just let it settle and then just act on the comments afterwards if they are problematic.

And even then maybe comment by saying:

> “Sorry, while your comment is well intentioned, this question is off topic and simply recommending one JavaScript library for such a broad topic such as media players doesn’t really add much.”

Comment: Unfortunately moderation is very much ad hoc, and on best effort. We're not going to likely to sit on a comment that we feel needs deleting. If it takes a while, its probably cause we haven't gotten to it yet.  Quick action saves everyone's time as well, since well, we might have folks getting 'taught' they can get an answer through an extended comment thread...