# I got my first downvote and I don't know why

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I'm pretty new to superuser and recently posted my first question as I was having trouble booting in haiku. ([Haiku panics at boot "vm_page_fault: unhandled page fault in kernel space"](https://superuser.com/questions/1733102/haiku-panics-at-boot-vm-page-fault-unhandled-page-fault-in-kernel-space))

I thought it was a pretty well written question, but still got downvoted.

I know that one downvote doesn't necessarily represent the community as a whole, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something wrong as the downvoter didn't leave a comment

Comment: As explained to you in the comments you need to file a bug report

Comment: @DavidPostill "go ask someone else" is not an acceptable answer

Comment: and I did file a bug report

Comment: only after you were told to.

Comment: @DavidPostill before that, actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got my first downvote and I don't know why

That's regrettably [typical](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14369/116475) on Stack Exchange. Downvoters can downvote for any reason, [without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179) any repercussion and without having to explain themselves.

> I wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something wrong as the downvoter didn't leave a comment

You're not doing something wrong, the question is ok.